# Customize Sharepoint User Interface - List Display

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, custom-list, list-form

I am currently working on site on SharePoint. I created all the lists I needed.

I am trying to make an User Interface. The futur users have an interface requirement but I don't know how to fulfull it :

- The editing grid view must be vertical and not horizontal, same for all the list view

I have been looking on the internet for many days for solutions but could not find any that worked on my site. I am not allowed to use neither Sharepoint Designer, nor InfoPath , and any other related softwares.

I tried several Javascript codes that I found online but the final effect is not what the clients are expecting to get and the scripts usually require to write Column Names of the lists in the parameters, but the users will add more columns in the future, and they don't want to modify the code.

Could you help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as a "too broad" question, because you are requesting help with several requirements and addressing each of them in one answer isn't ideal. Especially when the requirements include customizing it'll be quite unlikely to answer exactly to your requirements in one shot. Please edit your question to focus on one specific requirement. It's okay to create a new question for each of your requirement.

Comment: @moe Thank you for the information, i will edit my question

Comment: You can fetch the list metadata from the rest API and then only dynamically construct the view based on the fields you get back from it. This sounds like a lot of custom code is required which cannot be retrieved from GitHub, but you need to write it yourself.  Check the SPFields of the list... They have some properties "ShowinXXXForm" to help you to decide which fields to render XXX=Display/Edit/New. Alternative is PowerApps since you can implement it with little code there

Comment: @HeikoHatzfeld_MSFT Thank you for the answer. Do you have any code sample on fetching list metadata, so I can at least start from something existing and customize it as I need.

Comment: No code itself... this is the endpoint you want: http://site url/_api/web/lists(guid'list GUID')

I would take a look at customizing the list forms with powerapps 1st though. No need for code there